# How do I find the critical points of this function involving e?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I have the function:

$$g(x)={{1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{{-(x-2)^2}/2}}$$

Through very tedious differntion, I got to:

$$g'(x) = {{{-(x+2)} \cdot {e^{{-(x-2)^2}/2}}} \over {2 \pi}}$$

Setting $g'(x) =0$ like I was taught in class, I am unable to find the critical points. The farthest I can get is:

$$xe^{u} = 2e^u$$ where u = that annoying exponent.

Something tells me to take the ln of both sides, but I can't get it in a useful form to do so.

How do I proceed?

Comment: HINT: To solve $h(x)e^{g(x)}=0$, it's equivalent to solve $h(x)=0$ since $e^y$ can never be zero itself for any value of $y$.

Comment: So you're saying I can ignore the e and rewrite as $x = 2$ essentially?

Comment: hint: $e^x\neq0$

Comment: Yes, you can divide both sides by the $e$ part because it is never zero.

Comment: But be careful, you want $x=-2$, not $x=2$.

Comment: So there is no possible value of $x$ where ${e^x} = 0$?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only $x$ that makes that zero is $x=-2$.  Divide both sides by the $e^{\dots}$ part which you know is never zero.

Comment: How can the maximum be at $-2$?

Comment: I was assuming he did the derivative correctly, but the main point is the same in terms of how to solve the equation with an exponential term like that.

Answer (score 3):

If $g(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-2)^2}$, then

$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-2)^2} \times (-2(x-2))$$

for which $g'$ is zero only at $x=2$.

At $x=2$, we have $g(2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

This value is the maximum of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently WolframAlpha isn't enough to show you that your derivative is incorrect, so let me help you see for yourself.

We're starting out with this (edited for clarity)

$$g(x)=2\pi^\frac{-1}{2} * e^\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2}$$

I'm going to pull out the constant $2\pi^\frac{-1}{2}$ so now we have

$$2\pi^\frac{-1}{2}g(x)=e^\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2}$$

Using the chain rule, we get

$$2\pi^\frac{-1}{2}g'(x)=(\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2})'e^\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2}$$

Simplifying the derivative:

$$(\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2})' = (\frac{-2(x-2)}{2}) = -(x-2) = 2-x$$

Therefore

$$2\pi^\frac{-1}{2}g'(x)=(2-x)e^\frac{-(x-2)^2}{2}$$

And the only time that $g'(x)=0$ is when $x = +2$, so the critical point is

$$g(2) = 2\pi^\frac{-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complicated function  $g(x)$ involving a lot of products and exponentials ask [John Napier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier) for help. He would tell you to make it even more complicated $f(x)=\log(g(x))$. Then by the chain rule 
$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ or $g'(x)=g(x)\cdot f'(x)$.

What would be the gain? Well $\log(g(x))$ might be easier to differentiate.
In your case 
$\log(g(x))=\log(1/\sqrt{2\pi})-(x-2)^2/2$ and its derivative is $-(x-2)$
so that $g'(x)=g(x)\cdot(2-x)$